# Resize the widget in tab on TabBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, tabs, widget, tabbar

I am using a tab bar in my app and want to resize the widget inorder to fit the text and have the font size be bigger. I also don't want the tab bar to be scrollable. Is there a way to reduce the padding, or margins or whatever is being used?

Attached is a screenshot of what it currently looks like. The green background was for me to visualize the size. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdrHS.png)

Here is my code for the tab bar.

```
TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35),
              indicatorColor: CustomColors.wrkioBlue,
              isScrollable: false,

              onTap: (index) {
                pageController.jumpToPage(index);
              },
              tabs: const <Widget>[
                Tab(//child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6,
                    child: SizedBox(width: 80, child: AutoSizeText('Connections', maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                    color: CustomColors.wrkioBlue)))),
                Tab(//child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6,
                  child: SizedBox(width: 80, child: AutoSizeText('Network', maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                    color: CustomColors.wrkioBlue)))),
                Tab(//child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6,
                  child: SizedBox(width: 80, child: AutoSizeText('Chats', maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                    color: CustomColors.wrkioBlue)))),
              ],
            ),
```

I have tried using a sized box. Adding padding to the tab child. A few other things I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Set `isScrollable: true`

```dart
TabBar(
    controller: _tabController,
    labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35),
    indicatorColor: CustomColors.wrkioBlue,
    isScrollable: true, //this
```

Comment: As I said in my post I don't want it to be scrollable. I want the 3 tabs to be visible regardless of screen size.